# Как обратится к полю data в промисе (react)

Tags: reactjs, объекты, promise

[image: data]

Есть вот такой стейт

```
const [parsedCsvData, setParsedCsvData] = useState<string[]>([]);
```

в него через react-papaparse паршу .csv файл

```js
complete: (results) => {
  let objs: any = (results as unknown) as string[];
  objs = results
  console.log(objs)
  setParsedCsvData(objs)
},
```

и не знаю как потом получить data которую я засунул в parsedCsvData

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если `parsedCsvData` — промис, то через `parsedCsvData.then(data => { ... })`. Если это объект с данными, то... просто использовать. Во всяком случае, дайте больше информации в вопросе через [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1378594/edit), например, о том каким типом является `parsedCsvData`.